# Find oldest/youngest datetime object in a list

Tags: python, datetime, compare

I've got a list of datetime objects, and I want to find the oldest or youngest one. Some of these dates might be in the future.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_list = [
    datetime(2009, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2010, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2010, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2011, 10, 12, 10, 10), #future
    datetime(2012, 10, 12, 10, 10), #future
]
```

What's the most optimal way to do so? I was thinking of comparing datetime.now() to each one of those.

Comment: How about `max` and `min` ?

Comment: There wasn't any similar question up on stackoverflow, I did search through for an answer, so I'm sure it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Oldest:

```
oldest = min(datetimes)
```

Youngest before now:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
youngest = max(dt for dt in datetimes if dt < now)
```

Comment: You mean oldest? (`Oldest before now`)

Comment: In Python 3, I think this is flawed. If I give this array ["April2020", "March2020"], min will give me "April2020" as if min will give most recent. However, if I give it ["April2020", "January2021", "March2020"], min will give me "April2020". I'm pretty sure min will give the alphabetical lowest which is not necessarily the most recent date.

Comment: @ScottyBlades that's because in your example your values are strings (which happen to represent a date, but are not actually `date` values), so they can only really be compared alphabetically. If you instead had an array of `date` or `datetime` values, they would be compared correctly.

Answer (score 42):

Given a list of dates `dates`:

Max date is `max(dates)`

Min date is `min(dates)`

Answer (score 19):

Datetimes are comparable; so you can use `max(datetimes_list)` and `min(datetimes_list)`

Answer (score 8):

have u tried this :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as DT
>>> l =[]
>>> l.append(DT(1988,12,12))
>>> l.append(DT(1979,12,12))
>>> l.append(DT(1979,12,11))
>>> l.append(DT(2011,12,11))
>>> l.append(DT(2022,12,11))
>>> min(l)
datetime.datetime(1979, 12, 11, 0, 0)
>>> max(l)
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 11, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

The datetime module has its own versions of min and max as available methods. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: According to these docs, datetime.min() returns the smallest representable datetime, not the minimum of a list of datetimes.