# max date in python list

Tags: python, list, date

I have an list:

```
a=[datetime.date(2010,10,20),1,4,datetime.date(2013,10,20)]
```

As you can see the list contains different types of elements. How can I get the max date within the list?

My attempt:

```
from datetime import datetime
b=datetime.max(a)
print b
```

Answer (score 24):

For guidence [Find oldest/youngest datetime object in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922644/find-oldest-youngest-datetime-object-in-a-list)

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_list = [
    datetime(2009, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2010, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2010, 10, 12, 10, 10),
    datetime(2015, 2, 12, 10, 10), # future
    datetime(2016, 2, 12, 10, 10), # future
]
oldest = min(datetime_list)
youngest = max(datetime_list)
```

The prior post has filter to exclude future events

Answer (score 9):

First, keeping dates and integers together in the same list -- except as an intermediate step -- can be a sign your data structure isn't appropriate.  That said, you can easily take the max only of the dates by using a generator expression:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a=[datetime.date(2010,10,20),1,4,datetime.date(2013,10,20)]
>>> max(d for d in a if isinstance(d, datetime.date))
datetime.date(2013, 10, 20)
```

Comment: That's not very specific, so it's hard to help you find your mistake.