# Python- how do I get the object whose date field has the most recent value from a list of objects?

Tags: python, django, filter, get, iterable

I have a Django application in which I there are a number of projects. Each project can have a number of budgets, and every time a new budget is added to a project, the existing budgets for that project should have their `version_number` incremented by one. The 'current' budget should be the budget whose `version_number` is 0- so when trying to 'get' the current budget for use elsewhere in the code, I am doing things like:

```
budgetInstance = Budget.objects.get(project = project, version_number = 0)
```

However, it seems that somehow, some of the projects have ended up with a number of `budgets` whose `version_number` is 0, so it appears that some of the projects in the database seem to have several 'current budgets'...

I know that I will need to fix the logic for how the versioning is done, so that no two `budgets` can have the same `version_number`, but for now, I just want to get the most recent `budget` for each project in the database.

Each `Budget` object has attributes such as: `project_id`, `version_number`, `id`, `presentation_date`, etc.

So I now want to filter the `budgets` that have been returned when I filtered by `version_number = 0)` by their `presentation_date` field. As I understand, I would do this using `min()`, but I can't seem to get this working...

I tried following the accepted answer at: [Find oldest/youngest datetime object in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922644/find-oldest-youngest-datetime-object-in-a-list), and ran the following in the shell:

```
mostRecentBudget = min(date for date in budgets.dates if date < now)
```

But I got a `TypeError`, which said:

> TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable

Why is this? How can I search through the list of `Budgets` in a given `Project`, for the one with the most recent `presentation_date` field value?

Comment: You're going to need to give more information. What is `budgets` and `budgets.dates` here? And why can't you use the db to order this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter on [`Date[Time]Fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#datefield) with [`__lt[e]`, `__gt[e]`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#gt) and [date[time]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects. Then, use [`latest(field_name)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.datetime.now()
Budget.objects.filter(
    project=project, version_number=0, 
    presentation_date__lte=now  # p_d less than or equal now
).latest('presentation_date')
```

Unlike [`last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#last), but very much like [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get), this will raise an [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) if the [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) is empty.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm getting a `DoesNotExist` error message, as you mentioned I might, but I'm not sure why...? Why would the queryset be empty? If I run: `testPrjBdgtsv0 = testPrjBdgts.filter(version_number = 0)`, and then `testPrjBdgtsv0`, I get the following output: `[<Budget: Test 1: Version 0>, <Budget: Test 1: Version 0>, ... ]` so clearly the queryset is not empty...?

Comment: Then it shouldn't raise an exception. Are you sure you call latest on the exact same queryset? The qs in my example has a couple more filters.

Comment: I'm typing it exactly as you have written it in your answer there, but there's something a bit unusual happening when I type it: after typing the `__lte=`, the cursor moves back to the start of the line, so as I continue typing `now)`, that is all overwriting what was written at the start of the line...

Comment: It actually seems to have really messed up the input in the shell somehow... When I started typing on that line, the prompt said: `now[58]`, rather than `In [57]:` as it had on the previous input line... and every line after that (if I press Enter) just has `... :` I'm not sure why this is?

Comment: @someone2088 `ctrl + c` is your friend in the shell. `...` means the statement you are typing is not finished yet

Comment: Ok, so I exited that weird input, and did it again- I still get the `DoesNotExist` message you said I might

Comment: I am sure I call `latest` on the exact same queryset.... I've even manually retrieved the `budgets` individually to look at them... and I can see that they have differing values for their `version_date` properties...

Comment: And when you call latest on said queryset, it raises an exception? I am confused now with `version_date` and `presentation_date`. You will figure it out! ;)