# List of Dates & Search through a File

Tags: python

I have a file (JSON file) that contain multiple dates, hours and minutes.

How can I extract the latest date?
If the latest date contains 2 "timestamp" how do I use the hours/ minutes in order to extract the latest date?

For example -

1.

```
01/01/2018 16:23
07/02/2019 16:00
```

2.

```
05/02/2018 15:00
05/02/2019 15:05
```

I want to add the latest date to a file/ list.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklis)t and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) . **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find oldest/youngest datetime object in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922644/find-oldest-youngest-datetime-object-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import datetime

format_string = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

this is the string used to format the dates.
(I assumed you use Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute)

Here is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) with everything you can use.

```py
date_strings = [
 "01/01/2018 16:23",
 "07/02/2019 16:00",
 "05/02/2018 15:00",
 "05/02/2019 15:05"
]
```

this is the input list you can get it diffrent if you want.

```py
dates = []
for date_string in date_strings:
 date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format_string)
 dates.append(date)
dates.sort()
dates.reverse()
```

this will store the dates in `date`, sort and reverse them (the first is the newest and the last is the oldest).

```py
newest = dates[0].strftime(format_string)
print(newest)
```

this will print the newest date.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)  covers the same.